# WP API file_get_contents return TTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

Tags: rest-api

I've made this function to get the post id from WP Api , and Render it from server ( not by Js or Ajax ).

```
function api_featured_item_id($url) {

    $data = file_get_contents($url); // put the contents of the file into a variable
    $posts = json_decode($data,true); // decode the JSON feed

    $i = 0;
    $outuput = '';

    foreach( $posts as $item ) {
        $outuput .= $item['id'] .',';
        $i++;
        if($i==4) break;
    }

    return $outuput;
}
```

In local it work, after moving online, i've this error :

Warning: file_get_contents(https://website.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/5816?_embed): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized in /home/public_html/website.com/wp-content/mu-plugins/general-functions.php

If I try to open the url on browser, work fine and I can see the Json Data correctly.
I've set via PHP Ini the allow_url_fopen "enabled" , but not work.

Comment: Does the REST URL still work for you in an incognito / private browsing tab, i.e. when you're not logged in? Your request from the server won't be.

Comment: I assume this is a REST endpoint on a different server, though, not a request back to the same server? There's no point fetching data from yourself over the REST API when you can get it directly from the database.

Comment: Now work, the problem was a plugin that disable rest api. I use Rest API instead of Wp Query, because i want to test the performance ( I think Api call is better than Wp query )